# F# FSI "Unexpected compiler generated literal in interaction" with "#I __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__"

Tags: f#, fsi, amazon-fsx

If I create a new F# file 'Test.fsx' in VSCode with the line

```
#I __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
```

attempting to run the code in FSI generates the error

```
Test.fsx(2,4): error FS0010: Unexpected compiler generated literal in interaction. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point, ';', ';;' or other token.
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: You're just trying to reference a package in the same directory as `Test.fsx`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It also generates the same error in Visual Studio.

Comment: Check this and see if it works for you: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/property-based-testing/#using-fscheck-to-test-the-addition-properties
Also, if you're already in the same directory, you might be able to just `#r` or `#load` the files/assemblies you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue in VS2019, which has been fixed in VS2022.

https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/13467

You may replace the code with

```ml
#I "."
```